# If a new object is created in each recursion, is the space complexity O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

Assume the object is a dummy list node, it's only used in the same recursion level where it is created.

I feel the part I'm not sure about is whether the space of the object can be recycled when a recursion level finishes. If the space can be recycled, I would say the space complexity is O(1), otherwise I feel it's O(M) where M is the number of recursions.

Comment: > *otherwise I feel it's O(M) where M is the time of recursions.* ... Is that an unintentional slip from space to time?

Answer (score 1):

Being able to reclaim some (fixed size) objects associated with an activation frame doesn't change the asymptotic complexity. It only improves the constants of the actual resource use.

The algorithm's storage use is O(M) simply based on the number of activation frames it allocates at once, not their precise size.

Of course, using 100 bytes per frame is inarguably better than 1000 or 10000, but constant factors like that don't contribute to *complexity*, which is why we make them disappear in the O notation.

Knocking that down to O(1) will require a reorganization of the control flow itself, such a switch to tail calls or iteration.